# How do I return a function as an output value in MATLAB?

Tags: function, matlab, return

I am writing a function `makeFunction(data)`. I want it to return a function, not a matrix, vector, or scalar. How do I do this?

Answer (score 17):

Use function handles.

```
function f = functionReturner(u)
% creates the function x.^u to return as an example
f = @(x) x.^u;
```

If I save this function, then call functionReturner, the argument is itself a function.

```
f = functionReturner(3);
f(2.5)
ans =
       15.625
```

You can easily enough verify that 15.625 is indeed 2.5^3.

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using anonymous functions?

Comment: @Will - I don't know what problem you are trying to solve, or even what MATLAB release you are using. Is there a reason why you are now placing constraints on the answer? If you have some ulterior motive, tell us rather than making us all guess. Reading the crystal ball is so difficult some days.

Comment: If the anonymous part bothers you, a regular function handle to a subfunction will also work.

Comment: You can return a function handle, like @sin, but it is the same thing, just slightly less anonymous. You can also return an inline function.